# Why is my method name giving me an error?

Tags: c#, console-application

My method CalculateFee is giving me an error. It's just a red line under the name "CalculateFee"

I've tried changing public to private and that didn't help, and even int to void even though that was kinda stupid of me...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FineForOverdueBooks
{                   
    class Program   
    {               
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many books were checked out?");
                int booksCheckedOut = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            {
                if (booksCheckedOut == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many days is it overdue?");
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("How many days are they overdue?");
            }
            int daysOverdue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int output = CalculateFee(booksCheckedOut, daysOverdue);
            Console.WriteLine("Your late fee is: ", output.ToString("C"));
        }

    public static int **CalculateFee**(int booksCheckedOut, int daysOverdue)
    {
        double libraryFine = .10;
        double additionalFine = .20;
        if (daysOverdue <= 7)
        {
            for (double x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
            {
                libraryFine += .10;
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(libraryFine);
        }
        if (daysOverdue > 7)
        {
            for (int x =0; x<=daysOverdue; x++)
            {
                additionalFine += .20;
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(additionalFine);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I just want my method to be able to execute so I can see if I did my for loops correctly and if I need to change some stuff (which I probably do)

Sorry if this seems like a duplicate I couldn't find anything that directly pertained to my problem.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: not all code paths return a value

Comment: It's inside the class @ZoharPeled, it's just indented wrong.

Comment: you have error because you have 2 ifs. So you can replace the second if with else or at the end of your method you can put another return so all paths return a value.

Comment: @nbokmans Yes, the indentation confused me. I've deleted my comment once realizing that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2017

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the red line, the error message appears in a pop-up.

Answer (score 4):

Because `CalculateFee` doesn't return in all cases. Actually in this case it just doesn't static analyse all the values to know it can never get there. Consider using an `else`:

```
public static int CalculateFee(int booksCheckedOut, int daysOverdue)
{
   double libraryFine = .10;
   double additionalFine = .20;
   if (daysOverdue <= 7)
   {
      for (double x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
      {
         libraryFine += .10;
      }
      return Convert.ToInt32(libraryFine);
   }
   else
   {
      for (int x =0; x<=daysOverdue; x++)
      {
         additionalFine += .20;
      }
      return Convert.ToInt32(additionalFine);
   }

}
```

Comment: Actually, it does return in all cases, only the compiler does not catch up on that. If an int is not smaller than or equal to 7, it mush be bigger than 7. The correct thing to do is either remove the second condition or change it into the else block of the first one.

Comment: Basically, the compiler isn't clever enough to realise that `<=7` and `>7` cover all possible cases (and that you don't change `daysOverdue`). The fix is to replace the second `if` with `else`

Comment: @ZoharPeled The compiler can't be **sure** that `daysOverdue`'s value doesn't change between the two `if`s.

Comment: @mjwills How can it change it's value? it's a value type argument, so it's thread safe, and there's nothing in the code that's changing it....

Comment: @ZoharPeled `How can it change it's value?` In the debugger? ;) For it to accept this code, it would need to do static analysis to see that nothing is changing its value **and** not allow you to change it in the debugger. It isn't a 'clever-ness' issue like Robin claims, I don't think - it is actually **being** clever since it knows what it doesn't have control over (since it isn't `const`).

Comment: @mjwills Good point about the debugger. I didn't think about that.